# Microsoft Access accdb versus mdb

Tags: performance, ms-access, stability

I have to repair and piece together a very shaky database system that is used by several members of staff in the organisation I'm working in. This system has been replicated, duplicated, shared around and otherwise abused over its lifetime, along with various upgrades to all aspects of the design and table structure. The long and short of it is that the system has suffered and become rather unstable. I've managed to write a process (using manual means and VBA) that extracts the data, queries, forms, reports and macros to new databases (though I can't guarantee any of it, much).

I'd like to ask: are there any great performance differences that should sway me in favour of either *accdb* (Microsoft Access 2007 db format) or *mdb* (Microsoft Access 2003 db format)?  And, likewise, are there any great stability and structural integrity issues with either format that could affect such a decision?

*NOTE: The current version is mdb.*

Comment: The accdb format does not support user-level security, so if you are using that then you can't migrate. The other 'upgrades' in the new format are not performance-related.

Comment: @nicomp: That's not an issue, thankfully - the system users folder level security that only specific people can access.

Comment: The newer accdb format is advantageous from versions 2013 and later when connecting with SQL Server or Azure using the SQL Server Native Client over ODBC. That's mainly frontend, though. I have not heard of any decisive advantage for storing backend data in an accdb over mdb file.

Comment: You gain data macros (basically triggers) with accdb. Those can be very useful.

Comment: @Brad: Yes, that is a bonus, but doesn't really separate the sheep from the goats in respect to an existing system; I'd have to reassess the whole data structure and ascertain if there would be any benefit to adding data macros.

Comment: @Close Voter: Why is this question *'Primarily opinion based'*? Don't be ridiculous!